# Counting substrings in Python - more efficient approach?

Tags: python, substring, counting

So I've been learning Python for a couple months now.  I came across an exercise that wants you to count how many times a sub-string appears in a string.  I searched, but couldn't find quite the exact answer I was looking for.  Here is the code I wrote, that is functional.  However, it does take a second due to the exception.  I chose to use string.index because the -1 value from string.find in some words would mess up the starting point.  What is the more efficient way, without importing other modules, etc.  E.g. in more basic Python, such as the code I wrote.

```
word = "banana"
sub = "ba"
start = 0
ix = 0
count = 0
end = None

if end is None:
    end = len(word)
while start < end:
    if sub in word:
        try:
            ix = word.index(sub, start, end)
        except:
            break
        ix += 1
        start = ix + 1
        count += 1
print(count)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just do:

`'banana'.count('ba')`

The docs for the count method of strings say:

> Return the number of non-overlapping occurrences of substring sub in 
>   string S[start:end].  Optional arguments start and end are 
>   interpreted as in slice notation.

Sample output:

```
>>> 'banana'.count('ba')
1
>>> 'banana'.count('na')
2
```

Comment: /facepalm I read this in the documentation, but maybe I got confused with how simple it seemed.  Why am I tortured creating functions for functions that exist already? /sigh

Comment: @ChrisAvina Note however that this would result in `'banana'.count('ana') == 1` (non-overlapping) while what you have implemented would yield `2`